# is_enum<> in another template function does not work/compile

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I have a template function that's working fine if I don't use an `enum` as argument type (here in condensed form; it transforms a string into anotjer type using `stringstream`s):

```
template<typename T>
void section::getVal(std::string key,T& var)
{   
    std::stringstream ss; ss.str(key);
    ss>>var;
}
```

Now I want that function to work with any `enum`, so i tried

```
enum slimit {lower,higher,between,nolim};

template<typename T>
void section::getVal(std::string key,T& var)
{   
    std::stringstream ss; 
    ss.str(key);
    if(!std::is_enum<T>::value)
        ss>>var;
    else
    {  
        int h;
        ss>>h;
        var=static_cast<T>(h);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't compile

```
(error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::stringstream {aka std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>}' and 'sensact::slimit')
                ss>>var;)
```

If I replace `ss>>var;` with something that doesn't care for the type (`int n=0;`) it compiles and the if-distinction/ `is_enum` works perfectly and the else block is executed if `var` is an `enum` type.

So how can I get it to work and why does it not compile?

Answer (score 3):

While an `if` statement only *executes* one branch, it still *compiles* all the branches. Since the code is ill-formed in one of the branches, you get an error.

If you want to conditionally compile some branches, you can use `constexpr if` like this:

```
if constexpr (!std::is_enum<T>::value)
   ss >> var;
else
{  
  int h;   // in general, std::underlying_type_t<T> instead of int,
           // to allow for other enumeration types
  ss >> h;
  var=static_cast<T>(h);
}
```

---

Thanks to @Jarod42 for the `underlying_type` suggestion in the comment.

Comment: Nice but the OP doesn't tagged C++17: you should explicit that `if constexpr` is available only starting from C++17.

Comment: @max66 Fair point, but I've started trying to go with the tag wiki which says, "unless a version is mentioned, the current version is assumed". C++17 is 3 years old now, and to be honest, I'm tired of putting those version caveats in every answer :(

Comment: Yes... maybe is the time to accept that C++17 (if not C++20) is in charge.

Comment: @max66 Yeah, I tried it with a couple of C++20 solutions, but several users complained :p, so maybe not yet. But C++17 should be accepted at least :)

Comment: `int` -> `std::underlying_type_t<T>` to go further.

Comment: @Jarod42 Hey, that looks great, thanks. I learned something new :)

Comment: @Jarod42 I've edited the answer, if I've understood the suggestion correctly that is.

Comment: @AndiWerSonst Great :) Consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @Jarod42 No, I don't want to "fix" the code like that. But adding as a comment is better, edited, thanks.